# How do I restart Application Insights logging after daily cap reached

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am using Azure Application Insights to record requests, dependencies and errors in my application. I am only using the free tier, so the limit is 200mb a day.

Yesterday I hit the 200mb limit at about 10pm, and my recording has stopped and will not start again until 4pm UTC (according to the email alert I received).

I have since reduced the sampling amount until I can get things tidied up and reduce the amount of requests being logged.

However, I am looking for a way to manually restart the logging instead of waiting until 4pm for it to begin automatically.

Does anyone know if this is possible?
I have done some searching and I cannot find any mention of what I'm asking, so any help would be amazing.

Many thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK There is no way to restart the application insight after it reached the daily limit.

There are following ways you can achieve continuous logging without any obstruction

- Increase the daily limit of application insight by simple power shell script or from portal too.

```js
    Set-AzureRmApplicationInsightsDailyCap
       [-ResourceGroupName] <String>
       [-Name] <String>
       [-DailyCapGB <Double>]
       [-DisableNotificationWhenHitCap]
       [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
       [-WhatIf]
       [-Confirm]
       [<CommonParameters>]
```

- Other useful feature is you can use Sampling in your code base, Adaptive sampling is the most apt for your case which automatically adjusts the volume of telemetry sent from the SDK in your

you can refer this link for [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling).
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I was not aware that sampling could be applied in the code base. For anyone else out there, the only way I have found to restart application insights once the cap is reached is to increase the cap (in my test, increasing 0.19 to 0.2 worked), though this is not all that helpful.